# Using non-blocking tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task

The following code returns the incorrect product. I expect that I need to use the await term in my AsyncMultiply function and I tried adding it in front of all lines, but it didn't work. How can I fix the code so that the task becomes  a non-blocking, correctly calculating task?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NonBlockingTasks
{
    class Program
    {
        static int prod;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => { await AsyncMultiply(2, 3); });

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Prod = " + prod);

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
        {
          await Task.Delay(100);
        }           

        public static async Task<int> AsyncMultiply(int a, int b)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            prod = a * b;
            return prod;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I actually visited it before posting the question. Funny thing is that the author didn't show the part that causes my code not to work. I still don't know where to put the "await" in the function AsyncMultiply().

Comment: Hans, I am trying to use the return value - Console.WriteLine("Prod = " + prod); I want my WinForms program not freeze while I am doing one or more time consuming tasks. Can I use System.Threading.Tasks to keep my program responsive? My understanding is that non-blocking means that the program can do other things while a function is running in background.

Comment: The snippet shows the fundamental weaknesses of async/await.  It does not stop you from creating threading race bugs.  And it does not help you identify code that needs a synchronous result that is produced by asynchronous code.  Standard threading bugs, they just get much harder to identify.  It is therefore better for you to *not* use async/await.  BackgroundWorker in a winforms app has a much easier mental model.

Comment: Thanks Hans. That's funny. My first sample code was using BackgroundWorker and I was told I should use Threads. I created a sample code using Threads and I was advised I should use Tasks. Now I am told I should use BackgroundWorkers :)

Comment: Hmya, the real advice you need is to read at least 3 books about threading first.  But nobody is going to propose that, it is not considered helpful at SO.  And nobody is going to help you learn writing solid threaded code in an SO post.  So you're kinda stuck having to read those books :)  You won't regret it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task.Run returns a Task and you are not waiting for it to finish. If you are using C# 7.1 (.net 4.7) or greater you can surface the awaitable all the way to the caller:

```
        static int prod;
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task running  = Task.Run(async () => { await AsyncMultiply(2, 3); });

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            await running; // Wait for the previously abandoned task to run.


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Prod = " + prod);

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

        public static async Task<int> AsyncMultiply(int a, int b)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            prod = a * b;
            return prod;
        }
```

Otherwise, you can freeze the current thread, waiting for the task to complete:

```
        static int prod;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task running  = Task.Run(async () => { await AsyncMultiply(2, 3); });

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            running.Wait(); // Freeze thread and wait for task.


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Prod = " + prod);

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

        public static async Task<int> AsyncMultiply(int a, int b)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            prod = a * b;
            return prod;
        }
```

Comment: I use SharpDevelop and the highest .Net version is 4.5.2. I am getting confused about why I have to freeze the current thread. I can freeze my program (cause the interface not to respond while performing a long running function) even without using Tasks. The whole point of me trying to use Tasks is (I hope) to keep the form responsive to pressing buttons, etc, while some heavy computation runs in background. Are the Tasks good for this requirement?

Comment: @Nick_F You don’t have to freeze the current thread, nor should you. That’s the point of using tasks. But tasks need to be async all the way up. However, if you are using pre-C# 7.1 `Main` can’t be async so you need to use `Wait` in this case, which should normally be avoided.